# How to configure silverstripe 4 to use a BLOB field instead of the file system

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

In the Silverstripe 4 docs the possiblity to use a BLOB or s3 storage is mentioned (https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/v4/working-with-files-and-images-1)

But I cannot find any documention how to handle a BLOB storage. Is this only about configuration or is some implementation required? Are there examples?

Comment: SS4 uses the [PHPLeague's flysystem](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/) package under the hood - in theory you'd need to configure that to store the file contents in a DB blob field. It may require some custom code

Comment: that's what I'm looking for. I hoped for some docs or examples. But maybe i have to do it on my own

Comment: I tried to extend the Public and Protected Adapter ( SilverStripe\Assets\Flysystem\PublicAdapter) but it seems to have no effect in the admin asset manager

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom DBField class for BLOB.

Here is the example `DBBlobField` class works in SS 4.2 with MariaDB.

```
use SilverStripe\ORM\DB;
use SilverStripe\ORM\FieldType\DBField;

class DBBlobField extends DBField
{
    function requireField()
    {
        DB::require_field($this->tableName, $this->name, "mediumblob");
    }
}
```

`mediumblob` is the BLOB type supported by your database.

Define the $db field in DataObject.

```
private static $db = [
    "Data" => DBBlobField::class
];
```

Save file content into `Data` field.

```
$dataObject->Data = file_get_contents($filePath);
$dataObject->write();
```

Comment: This may be a proper solution for a special data record but does not work for the hole application and the asset manager